# Thread work balance in a Producer-Consumer implementation

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a basic implementation of producer-consumer as follows:

[image]

My question is how to make number of threads: x ~ y to increase application performance and loading balance? 
Anyone have a keyword or hint? Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to compute optimal sizes of the `x` and `y` thread pools by working from [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law): you basically need to know how often new work arrives and how long on average it takes to handle each work item.